# NSPredicate for two NSNumber arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a bit of a hard time writing a predicate for my search functionality and thought you'd be bale to help. So basically I have two arrays of NSNumbers. I want my predicate to satisfy the following:

```
If a number's integerValue in array A matches any integerValue in array B.
```

I don't want to use any sort of loop for this solution. Here's what I have so far

```
ANY integerValue == ANY //how do I pass the entire array here and ask for the integerValue of each member?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ANY operator will handle that.

Since it is a bit difficult to say from your question which of the arrays is "self" in normal predicate parlance, I'll write it without a self:

```
NSArray *arrayA = @[@2, @3, @7];
NSArray *arrayB = @[@2, @4, @9];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY %@ IN %@", arrayA, arrayB];
```

Due to the lack of a "self", it will have to be evaluated with `nil` as the object, but that works fine:

```
BOOL matched = [pred evaluateWithObject: nil];
```

If you prefer to have a "self" in the predicate, you can just enter it:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY self IN %@", arrayB];
BOOL matched = [pred evaluateWithObject: arrayA];
```

The result is the same.

#### A small conceptual comment

The predicate above evaluates to true if any integer is included in both arrays, which is how I read your question.

This means that, conceptually speaking, you seem to be testing whether two sets of numbers intersect each other. `NSSet`'s method  `intersectsSet:` checks that, so another way to do the test would be to keep your numbers as sets and test for intersection:

```
matched = [setA intersectsSet: setB];
```

Comment: Great answer. I wouldn't recommend the second solution though, since it'd imply quite an overhead (deriving sets from arrays) just to be able to test for set intersection.

Comment: @matehat you're right - my comment on the set was more of a conceptual nature, so I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Great answer! Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not precisely what you asked for (predicates and all) but another way is to use `NSArray`'s  `- (id) firstObjectCommonWithArray:(NSArray *)otherArray`, which would return `nil` if no common object can be found.

```
BOOL arraysIntersect = [array1 firstObjectCommonWithArray:array2] != nil;
```

One caveat though is that it would use its own object equality rules when comparing two objects, meaning if two objects are NSNumber instances, it will compare them using `NSNumber`'s `compare:` method. But the same goes for the predicate-based solution proposed so far.